# Excel VBA Cell value rounded when passed to an array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping this has a simple solution. I need to take values in from a worksheet, perform calculations and insert them into a hidden worksheet (to be uploaded later into a database). I don't normally program in VBA, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My problem is this: when I copy data from the worksheet into the array, they are rounded like an integer when I've specified long. The following code snippet will give you an idea of the problem. Am I initializing the array wrong?

```
 Dim ThisWS As Worksheet
 Set ThisWS = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BchSheet")
 Dim BTW() As Long                       'Beaker Tare Weight
 ReDim Preserve BTW(Samples)
 BTW(1) = ThisWS.Cells(18, 6).Value      'Value in cell is 98.7036
 MsgBox (ThisWS.Cells(18, 6).Value)      'Returns 98.7036
 MsgBox (BTW(1))                         'Returns 99
```

Comment: Long is in integer data type - Just allowing for larger values. convert it to `Double` and all should be good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Long` data type, like `Integer`, only holds whole numbers.

Use the `Double` data type to store decimals, or the `Currency` data type if you are working with calculations where fixed-point is necessary or you don't want to deal with floating-point numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple! I feel a little stupid now.